# How can I link two objects

Tags: custom-object

I have two separate accounts from the same organizations, Account reps. need these accounts linked but not merged.

Comment: There are several types of relationships and ways to accomplish this goal. See this reference for details about the types or relationships and determine which best suits your needs. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&language=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make one a child-account of the other, or make both records be children of another "master" account for that organization?

Answer (score 1):

There is a field named **parent account** in the Account.You can use that.